# How to integrate the static library in xamarin.ios which is generated from xcode targets (.a file)? how to call those methods in xamarin.ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xaml, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to use some objective-c files in xamarin.ios and i'm trying to create a static library from xcode targets it is generating the(.a file). my question is how to call those methods in xamarin.ios.

Comment: and how to integrate that .a file in xamarin.ios

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the library. Please refer to the Xamarin official documentations on this:

- [Walkthrough: Binding an iOS Objective-C Library](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/binding_objective-c/walkthrough/)
- [Binding Objective-C](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/)

Comment: its working. @kevin, I need to learn the xamarin forms can you please suggest me which is the best tutorials & If possible can you share the best practice links for that, It is very helpful for me.

Comment: @KmvSatish, you can refer to the Xamarin official documentations:[Getting Started with Xamarin.Forms](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/).

Comment: If my answer is helpful, could you please accept it?

Comment: @KmvSatish could you please mark it like this: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235, if it is helpful?